# i'm getting segmentation fault while using malloc with string pointers

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc

when i'm tryin' to use malloc with string pointers to scan, it's givin' a segmentation fault

```
main(){
    char *a;
    a = (char)malloc(50);
    printf("enter a string\t");
    scanf("%s", a);
    printf("%s\n", a);
}
```

Comment: 1. specify the return type of `main`, 2. specify the arguments `main` expects (ie `void`) 3. Remove the cast! 4. `return 0;` should be the last statement in `main` 5. Consider using _the stack_, not the heap for something this trivial

Comment: i tried all of 'em and it's still givin' segmentation fault

Comment: @user3248186 The hints from Elias Van Ootegem are just tipps to improve your `C`. They have nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: @pzaenger: It does solve the problem, if OP removes the cast, and the input is less than 50 chars, the code works (tried it myself)... to the OP: post the code you tried, following my advise

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: Oops, I see, you are right. Haven't seen, that it is a wrong cast. Sorry :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = (char)malloc(50);
```

Here, you meant to cast its type to `char *` instead of `char`.

Note that it's better not to cast the return type of `malloc`. See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/17012303#17012303)

Comment: Actually it is not better: you simply don't cast the result of `malloc`. However, the OP should read the accepted answer in your given link.

Answer (score 2):

Your *main* problem, apart from your using `scanf` is that you're casting a pointer (which is size 4 or 8 on 32 or 64 bit systems respectively) to a `char`, which is guaranteed to be size 1 as per standard.
 ***Do not ignore compiler warnings***. You should've seen something along the lines of:

```
warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
  a = (char) malloc(10);

warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  a = (char) malloc(50);
```

Casting a pointer type to `char`, only to assign it to a pointer variable *makes no sense*. If you want to make it absolutely clear that you are allocating enough memory to accomodate N chars, then you *could* write:

```
a = malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
//or better still
a = malloc(50 *sizeof *a);//50 times the size of whatever type a is pointing to...
```

But a char is *always* size 1, like I said before. Anyway: I set about fixing the code you posted:

The following copy-pasted code works just fine, provided you don't enter more than 49 chars:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    char *a = malloc(50);
    if (a == NULL) return EXIT_FAILURE;//<-- no memory available
    printf("enter a string\t");
    scanf("%s", a);
    printf("%s\n", a);
    free(a);//<== be tidy, free your memory, though here, it's a bit redundant
    return 0;
}
```

But really, [look into alternatives to `scanf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf), and *never* cast the pointer returned by `malloc` in C. C++ is a different matter.
Also, check for NULL pointers, to be safe.

Lastly: Don't ignore compiler warnings.

## [copy-paste & test here](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php)

you can provide stdin input at the bottom right hand side of the page, it'll print the string you provided